How to Install a PWA in a Completely Isolated Network?
I have a Progressive Web App (PWA) that needs to be deployed in a completely isolated and private network. The key constraints and requirements are as follows:

No External Hosting: The private network is entirely isolated, so users cannot access my website or any external resources to install the PWA.
No Hosting Within the Private Network: I am unable to host my app on any server within the private network.
Centralized Updates: Users' devices are managed via an internally-maintained Mobile Device Management (MDM) system, which handles app updates automatically. This eliminates the need for users to manually update the app.

Given these constraints, is it possible to package and deploy the PWA for installation on users' devices through the MDM system? If so:

How can the PWA be packaged in a way that meets MDM distribution requirements (e.g., as an .apk, .ipa, .msix, etc.)?
How can I install the PWA directly onto devices via USB or an external drive?
Are there any best practices for ensuring that the PWA retains its offline capabilities and behaves as intended in this scenario?

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.
